Как убрать отображение степени на графике matplotlib?
Можно ли как-то убрать отображение степени 1е7 вверху графиков?
Конечно, я могу предварительно разделить на 10^7, но верится, что есть более аккуратный способ, предусмотренный библиотекой matplotlib.


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Поделите данные и позвольте библиотеке делать своё дело.
